# Android:How two different modules implemented in one project communicate with each other with some data involving view?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, implementation, android-module

Basic Example:

Android Module 1 has a Button with a data String x= "Data From Module 1";

Android Module 2 has a Textview;

In another android Project which implements both Module 1 and Module 2, when the Button(Module 1) is clicked, Textview(Module 2) should show x value "Data From Module 1" in the view.

Android: Module 1 and Module 2 are Implemented in a Common Project:

[image: Android: Module 1 and Module 2 are Implemented in a Common Project]

My Issue:
Android Module 1 has a Google Map with a data LatLng of a place X;

Android Module 2 has customized Markers.

In another android Project which implements both Module 1 and Module 2, when the LatLng from Module 1 is passed to Module 2 to plot the customized marker.
What is the implementation for Communication between module 1 and module 2?

Comment: Please check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers